# Sublime Text 3 cannot install packages via packages control

Tags: sublimetext3

I install ST3 in my mac and have installed packages control. But today when I want to run "Package Control: Install Package" command, ST3 tell me "There are no packages available for installation".

The following is my debug console info:

```
Package Control: Fetching list of available packages
Platform: osx-x64
Sublime Text Version: 3065
Package Control Version: 3.0.1
Package Control: Download Debug
URL: https://packagecontrol.io/channel_v3.json
Resolved IPv6: 2600:3c02::f03c:91ff:fedf:6883
Resolved IP: 50.116.33.29
Timeout: 30
Package Control: Urllib Debug Proxy
http_proxy: 
https_proxy: 
proxy_username: 
proxy_password: 
Package Control: Found previously exported CA bundle at /Users/Morgan/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages/User/Package Control.system-ca-bundle
Package Control: Urllib HTTPS Debug General
Connecting to packagecontrol.io on port 443
Package Control: Urllib HTTPS Debug General
Connecting to packagecontrol.io on port 443
CA certs file at /Users/Morgan/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages/User/Package Control.merged-ca-bundle
Package Control: Error downloading channel. URL error _ssl.c:534: The handshake operation timed out downloading https://packagecontrol.io/channel_v3.json.
error: Package Control

There are no packages available for installation
```

How can I fix this? Please

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have a proxy and Package Control doesn't know it yet. Press CMD + SHIFT + P, then enter `Preferences: Package Control Settings - User` and add http_proxy or/and https_proxy parameters:

```
"http_proxy": "webproxy_address.com:3100",
"https_proxy": "webproxy_address.com:3100",
```

And then reload Sublime. I hope it helps.